# The difference between onErrorResume and doOnError

Tags: spring, project-reactor

In spring project reactor, what are the differences between `onErrorResume` and `doOnError` ? and when I should each of them ?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`onErrorResume`: Gives a fallback stream when some exception occurs happens in the upstream.

`doOnError`: Side-effect operator. Suppose you want to log what error happens in the upstream.

Example:

```
Mono.just(request)
.flatMap(this::makeHTTPGet)
.doOnError(err -> {
        log.error("Some error occurred while making the POST call",err)
    })
.onErrorResume(err -> Mono.just(getFallbackResponse()));
```

You see, `doOnError` is a side-effect operator. It's like inserting a thermometer into a water pipeline and reading the temperature. Does it affect the pipeline at all? No.

Suppose now that the pipeline breaks - the city still has to get water right? So we have a fallback pipeline that can be activate in such cases. `onErrorResume` does exactly that.

Note: You could also log in `onErrorResume`. Nothing stops you from doing that.

Comment: @MeladBasilius did this work for you? If yes, then please consider accepting it. Thanks.

Comment: this is great explanation buddy !!

Comment: Good analogy.  I noticed that if you pair this with a `then` in your pipeline, both the `onErrorResume` and `then` will be called.  If you provide a `doOnError`, only that is called, and the `then` is never called.