# Handle multiple external services using project reactor

Tags: java-8, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am new to reactive programming and trying to simulate the below use case using project reactor but I see little bit difficult to pass the response from one service call to another dependent service. Any suggestions or references will be highly appreciated.

Response  getDetails(Request inputRequest){

```
    //Call two external services parallel based on the incoming request 
        Response1 = callExternalService1(inputRequest)
        Response2 = callExternalService2(inputRequest)


    //Call one external service based on the Response1 and Response2
        Response3 = callExternalService3(Response1,Response2);


    //Call three external service parallel based on the Response1, Response2 and Response3
        Response4 = callExternalService4(Response1,Response2,Response3);
        Response5 = callExternalService5(Response1,Response2,Response3);
        Response6 = callExternalService6(Response1,Response2,Response3);


    //Last service call
       Response finalResponse= callLastExternalService(Response4,Response5,Response6);
       return finalResponse;

}
```

I tried the below sample and it's working for one service call but not able to pass the response to other dependent service calls.

Updated answer:

```
Mono<Response> getDetails(Request inputRequest){
    
    return Mono.just(inputRequest.getId())
                    .flatMap(id->{
                        DbResponse res = getDBCall(id).block();
                        if(res == null){
                            return Mono.error(new DBException(....));
                        }
                        return Mono.zip(callExternalService1(res),callExternalService2(inputRequest));
                    }).flatMap(response->{
                        Response extser1 = response.getT1();
                        Response extser2 = response.getT2();
                        //any exceptions?
                        return Mono.zip(Mono.just(extser1),Mono.just(extser2),callExternalService3();
                    }).flatMap(response->callExternalService4(response.getT1(),response.getT2(),response.getT3())
                    });
}

private Mono<DbResponse> getDBCall(String id) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(()->dbservice.get(id))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
}
```

**Questions:**

1. How to convert Mono<DbResponse>  to DbResponse without using block
   operation?
2. If any of the external service failed, how to build the
   failure response inside the flatmap and return back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have n calls and you want to move in steplock (that is, move ahead iff you have the response from all the calls), use `zip`. For instance:

```
Mono.zip(call1, call2)
    .flatMap(tuple2 -> {
         ResponseEntity<?> r1 = tuple2.getT1();    //response from call1
         ResponseEntity<?> r2 = tuple2.getT2();    //response from call2
         return Mono.zip(Mono.just(r1), Mono.just(r2), call3);
     })
    .flatMap(tuple3 -> {
         //at this point, you have r1, r2, r3. tuple3.getT1() response from call 1
         return Mono.zip(call4, call5, call6);   //tuple3.getT2() response from call 2, tuple3.getT3() response from call3
     })
    .flatMap(tuple3 -> callLastService);
```

Note: If is more of a pseudo-code, won't compile right away

You can extend the above to answer your own question. Note that since `call1` and `call2` are independent, you can run them parallely using `subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`

Edit: Answering the two follow-up questions:

1. No need to subscribe using `block()` as `flatMap` subscribes to your inner streams eagerly. You can do something like:

   ```
    Mono.just(inputRequest.getId())
        .flatMap(a -> getDBCall(a).switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> Mono.error(..))))
   ```

Note: `Mono.callable(..)` returns an empty stream if the callable returns empty. That's why `switchIfEmpty`

2. You can use operators like `onErrorResume` to provide a fallback stream. See: [The difference between onErrorResume and doOnError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58167842/the-difference-between-onerrorresume-and-doonerror/58178597#58178597)

Comment: if anyone of the services takes a long time will the main thread exit?. Don't we use block operation to wait for all the external services to get processed?

Comment: You don't need to block here. As I said, zip works in a steplock, so when the above stream emits, it'll be the response of the last service. The main thread exits as soon as the I/O call is offloaded to the elastic thread. You don't need to block anywhere here. You can try running the code once and check if it works for you.

Comment: Prashant , yes it is working +1.  I have posted two questions, could you please help?

Comment: @Prasanth, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

if your services return Mono of Response (otherwise you have to transform them), you can make parllel calls using zip :

```
    Mono.zip( callExternalService1( inputRequest ),
              callExternalService2( inputRequest ) )
        .flatMap( resp1AndResp2 -> this.callExternalService3( resp1AndResp2.getT1(),
                                                              resp1AndResp2.getT2() )
                                       .flatMap( response3 -> Mono.zip( callExternalService4( resp1AndResp2.getT1(),
                                                                                              resp1AndResp2.getT2(),
                                                                                              response3 ),
                                                                        callExternalService5( resp1AndResp2.getT1(),
                                                                                              resp1AndResp2.getT2(),
                                                                                              response3 ),
                                                                        callExternalService6( resp1AndResp2.getT1(),
                                                                                              resp1AndResp2.getT2(),
                                                                                              response3 ) )
                                                                  .flatMap( resp4AndResp5AndResp6 -> callLastExternalService( resp4AndResp5AndResp6.getT1(),
                                                                                                                              resp4AndResp5AndResp6.getT2(),
                                                                                                                              resp4AndResp5AndResp6.getT3() ) ) ) );
```

Comment: While this should work, there is unnecessary nesting which is usually a code smell.

Comment: The idea behind my answer is to explain how to make parallel calls using reactor (as it was requested). But, if he want to have a cleaner code, he can extract the different blocks according to his business logic. In this case it is necessary to have a concrete example...So your downvote is inappropriate!

Comment: I just read SO's guidelines on downvotes, and they recommend that we downvote when the answer is really wrong. This answer is not - So I guess that a downvote was unwarranted here. If you can change anything in answer, I can take the downvote back (my vote is now locked unless you edit your answer). On a different note though, you can still make parallel calls without nesting.